Idempotent Armendariz rings
Is there a mistake in this paper or I am understanding it incorrectly? They defined an idempotent Armendariz ring.
Idempotent Armendariz ring: A ring $R$ is said to be idempotent Armendariz (id-Armendariz) if whenever polynomials  $p(t)=\displaystyle\sum_{i=0}^{n}a_it^i$ and $q(t)=\displaystyle\sum_{j=0}^{m}b_jt^j$ in $R[t]$ satisfy $p(t)q(t)=0$, then $(a_ib_j)^2 =a_ib_j$ for each $i,j$. In theorem $2.12$ of this paper, they proved that $R$ is id-Armendariz if and only if $R[x]$ is id-Armendariz. I think this is not possible because the only idempotents of $R[x]$ are the idempotents of $R$. For example in some ring $R[x]$  the degree of $x$ will increase when we square the polynomial.

Okay, I accept that. Now, I will try to find a counterexample to clear it more

I am editing the last line

After the edit, i'm not clear on why you think something is not possible.  If $a_i$ and $b_j$ are elements of $R[x]$ are such that $a_ib_j$ is idempotent, what is wrong if it turns out that $a_i$ and $b_j$ are constant polynomials, i.e. elements of $R$?

By the way, it might be good to avoid \mathcal in your posts. I say this because for some users (me included) there is a manual process for telling chrome the right way to render it, and if it is not rendered they all look like squares.  It's a one-time thing, but I think for less savvy users it might never get resolved.

Okay will avoid it next time
